# How to reference hello.bmp inside my .app?

Tags: macos, xcode

I'm following the lazyfoo tutorials on SDL and I'm on lesson 01, getting an image on the screen, but SDL is giving me "Couldn't load hello.bmp", and I can't figure out why.

I'm using OS X, Xcode 3.2, and the latest version of SDL from their website.

I suspect it has something to do with not loading the hello.bmp image into Xcode correctly, but I've followed the tutorial and further Googling has produced no helpful results. Does anyone know how to troubleshoot this further?

Edit: It seems it has to do with relative paths. Still not sure what part is wrong though...

Edit: I've figured out that by going to Project -> Edit Active Executable and changing Set The Working Directory to 'Project Directory' works for now, but I don't understand why it won't load the hello.bmp in the .app itself. What am I missing?

Edit: Below is the source code for the lazyfoo lesson 01, included as per request. This is the code I'm using character for character, if you need any information about my XCode (Version 3.2), let me know.

```
/*This source code copyrighted by Lazy Foo' Productions (2004-2012)
and may not be redestributed without written permission.*/

//Include SDL functions and datatypes
#include "SDL/SDL.h"

int main( int argc, char* args[] )
{
    //The images
    SDL_Surface* hello = NULL;
    SDL_Surface* screen = NULL;

    //Start SDL
    SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING );

    //Set up screen
    screen = SDL_SetVideoMode( 640, 480, 32, SDL_SWSURFACE );

    //Load image
    hello = SDL_LoadBMP( "3.app/Contents/Resources/hello.bmp" );

    //Apply image to screen
    SDL_BlitSurface( hello, NULL, screen, NULL );

    //Update Screen
    SDL_Flip( screen );

    //Pause
    SDL_Delay( 2000 );

    //Free the loaded image
    SDL_FreeSurface( hello );

    //Quit SDL
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This should be asked on Stack Overflow, but without your code it will get closed there fairly quickly. Edit to include your code and I'll migrate.

Comment: Added sourcecode, sorry couldn't figure out how to properly format it without having to manually append four spaces to the beginning of each line. I was sure I remembered a way of doing it with one or two lines but if there was, it's gone now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is incorrect:

```
SDL_LoadBMP( "3.app/Contents/Resources/hello.bmp" );
```

You should get the path for a resource in your application's bundle by calling `[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"hello" ofType:@"bmp"]`, which will return an `NSString` object with the absolute path of the file corresponding to that resource.

Comment: Your question is tagged `osx` and you are asking how to access a file within a Mac app's bundle.  If you're developing for Linux too, you'll need to include a lot more information about what it is you are doing and which frameworks you are using, because your question doesn't apply to typical Linux applications at all.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that by replacing "hello.bmp" in the lesson01 source code with "X.app/Contents/Resources/hello.bmp" where X is the name of your XCode project, this correctly references the app that is built even if the .app is copied to the desktop and ran there.

Also, don't forget to add hello.bmp to the XCode project.

Comment: Note, this solution is not cross-platform and is therefor not ideal.